# decomposing objects in angular

Tags: angularjs

im fairly new to angular. im trying to understand why this doesnt work:

error recieved is:

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module phonecatApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module phoneList due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined**

```
angular.
module('phoneList').
component(name, component);

var name = 'phoneList';
var component = {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', function PhoneListController($http) {
        var self = this;
        self.orderProp = 'age';

        $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
            self.phones = response.data;
        });
    }]
};
```

how can i fix this ?

i know i can do this but i prefer decomposing the object as above. please advise

```
    angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', function PhoneListController($http) {
      var self = this;
      self.orderProp = 'age';

      $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
        self.phones = response.data;
      });
    }]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to define the name and component `var`s before using them in `.component(name, component)` ? Like:

```
var name = 'phoneList';
var component = {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', function PhoneListController($http) {
        var self = this;
        self.orderProp = 'age';

        $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
            self.phones = response.data;
        });
    }]
};

angular.
module('phoneList').
component(name, component);
```

Comment: sure bro! I'm glad I was of help

Answer (score -1):

this is the index.html. i already have app.module.js defining this

```
'use strict';

// Define the `phonecatApp` module
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phoneDetail',
  'phoneList'
]);


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-list/phone-list.module.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-list/phone-list.component.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-detail/phone-detail.module.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

this is not the issue. my example is straight from the angularjs tutorial with the above only difference of separating the component object from the component itself.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  Don't use the answer block to make comments or add additional details to your question, [edit] the question instead.